# Replace numbers in numpy array based on another array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector, binary

I have a target array/vector which is a combination of 1s and 0s. It is sparse (6% ones and the rest is 0) but when there are 1s typically there are 3 or so in a row. Example of the target array = [1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,...].

I also have a matrix that has the same number of rows as the aforementioned target array. Each column of the matrix is also filled with 1s and 0s. For each column, I want to do so that there is only a single 1 in each 'region' where there was a 1 in the target array.

For example, if the first column in the matrix is [1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,...] then this would become [1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,...] based on the example target array given earlier.

Notice that within each 'region' of 1s in the target array only the first 1 in the region of that column is kept. Also notice that 1s in the column outside the 'region' are not affected.

How can I perform this in numpy efficiently? Any help is much appreciated :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
import numpy as np

mask=np.array([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0], dtype=np.uint8)
col=np.array([1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0], dtype=np.uint8)
part1=~mask&col
part2=np.uint8(np.diff(np.insert(mask&col,0,0))==1)
res=part1|part2
print(res)
```